Make iPhone documents show up automatically in Files on Debian 12 (Testing)
When using Ubuntu 24.04 or Debian 11 and I plug in my iPhone 8 with a usb cable the Gnome Files app (and MATE's equivalent) show both iPhone's DCIM volume as well as the iPhone's documents (shared app files) volume in the sidebar as two separate volumes.
When I do the same on Debian 12 (that has been upgraded to Debian Testing) I only see the DCIM volume in the sidebar of Gnome Files.
I'm wondering if there's a specific component that I'm missing that mounts this volume and makes it available automatically in the Files app? I already have libimobiledevice-1.0-6 and the equivalent ...-glue-1.0-0 packages installed.
I've seen an answer about ifuse but that appears to be a manual workaround, and my experience tells me it's possible to have it done automatically when plugging in the phone.
Both gnome-shell and nautilus are version 47.0 (from Debian unstable).
Update
ifuse also doesn't show me what I'm looking for, which is the shared files by individual apps — instead it shows a raw and locked down directory hierarchy that I don't have much use for.

As a workaround for your ifuse problem, the command actually accepts a positional argument App ID, and a --documents argument.
You can get the ID with
ifuse --list-apps

and then do
ifuse ~/somedir --documents "com.somecompany.someapp"

where somedir is a mountpoint target, and com.somecompany.someapp is an App ID.

Thanks for the suggestion! Sounds pretty useful -- I'll try it out when possible.

This works as advertised. Good to know, thanks!
